# System freezes randomly (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, freeze

Recently my system (Ubuntu 18.04) my system freezes from time to time. It is completely unresponsive and even sending rusieb does not seem to get it out of it.

This is the syslog of the latest freeze:

```
Aug  2 15:13:22 dino-XPS-13-9360 gnome-shell[3088]: gnome-session gave us a dead inhibitor: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor37
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.326552] rfkill: input handler enabled
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 systemd[2906]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gvfsd[3066]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 systemd[2906]: xdg-permission-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 systemd[2906]: xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372562] swap_info_get: Bad swap file entry 2e01ffffffffffff
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372566] BUG: Bad page map in process dconf worker  pte:bc00000000000000 pmd:200b31067
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372569] addr:000000009624b89b vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:00000000a3d9dd6d index:139
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372576] file:libcanberra-gtk3-module.so fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372579] CPU: 0 PID: 3277 Comm: dconf worker Tainted: G    B D    OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372580] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/05HM5Y, BIOS 1.3.2 01/18/2017
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372581] Call Trace:
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372587]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372591]  print_bad_pte+0x222/0x2e0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372594]  ? __swap_info_get+0x7b/0xa0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372596]  ? _swap_info_get+0x12/0x50
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372598]  unmap_page_range+0x91f/0xd00
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372600]  unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372603]  unmap_vmas+0x51/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372606]  exit_mmap+0xb5/0x1d0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372610]  mmput+0x57/0x140
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372612]  do_exit+0x352/0xb90
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372614]  ? try_to_wake_up+0x59/0x4a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372616]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372619]  get_signal+0x142/0x7a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372622]  do_signal+0x37/0x720
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372625]  ? eventfd_write+0x95/0x270
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372628]  ? ktime_get_ts64+0x51/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372631]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0x73/0xd0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372633]  do_syscall_64+0x121/0x130
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372636]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372638] RIP: 0033:0x7f17b9639cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372640] RSP: 002b:00007f17b0302af0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000007
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372642] RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 000055bc79a09e70 RCX: 00007f17b9639cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372643] RDX: 00000000000061a8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000055bc79a09e70
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372645] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000055bc79a09f88
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372646] R10: 000055bc79a0f920 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 00000000000061a8
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372647] R13: 00000000000061a8 R14: 00007f17bb5d7070 R15: 0000000000000001
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372650] swap_info_get: Bad swap offset entry 3ffff994c312c
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372651] BUG: Bad page map in process dconf worker  pte:cd679da6a8 pmd:200b31067
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372653] addr:0000000014eda8b3 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:00000000a3d9dd6d index:13a
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372657] file:libcanberra-gtk3-module.so fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372659] CPU: 0 PID: 3277 Comm: dconf worker Tainted: G    B D    OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372660] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/05HM5Y, BIOS 1.3.2 01/18/2017
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372661] Call Trace:
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372664]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372666]  print_bad_pte+0x222/0x2e0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372668]  ? __swap_info_get+0x61/0xa0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372670]  ? _swap_info_get+0x12/0x50
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372673]  unmap_page_range+0x91f/0xd00
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372676]  unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372678]  unmap_vmas+0x51/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372680]  exit_mmap+0xb5/0x1d0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372683]  mmput+0x57/0x140
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372685]  do_exit+0x352/0xb90
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372687]  ? try_to_wake_up+0x59/0x4a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372688]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372690]  get_signal+0x142/0x7a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372692]  do_signal+0x37/0x720
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372694]  ? eventfd_write+0x95/0x270
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372696]  ? ktime_get_ts64+0x51/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372699]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0x73/0xd0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372700]  do_syscall_64+0x121/0x130
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372702]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372703] RIP: 0033:0x7f17b9639cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372704] RSP: 002b:00007f17b0302af0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000007
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372706] RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 000055bc79a09e70 RCX: 00007f17b9639cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372707] RDX: 00000000000061a8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000055bc79a09e70
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372708] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000055bc79a09f88
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372709] R10: 000055bc79a0f920 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 00000000000061a8
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.372710] R13: 00000000000061a8 R14: 00007f17bb5d7070 R15: 0000000000000001
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.373932] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:00000000b0feecf1 idx:2 val:-2
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 deja-dup-monito[4696]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 deja-dup-monito[4696]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 deja-dup-monito[4696]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 deja-dup-monito[4696]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 deja-dup-monito[4696]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gsd-housekeepin[3244]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gnome-session[2943]: gnome-session-binary[2943]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gnome-session-binary[2943]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gnome-session[2943]: gnome-session-binary[2943]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gnome-session-binary[2943]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 evolution-calen[3597]: Error releasing name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx3405x2: The connection is closed
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 evolution-calen[3597]: e_intervaltree_destroy: assertion 'E_IS_INTERVALTREE (tree)' failed
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 evolution-addre[3664]: Error releasing name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.AddressBookx3638x2: The connection is closed
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418874] swap_info_get: Bad swap offset entry 3ffff994c312c
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418879] BUG: Bad page map in process gdbus  pte:cd679da6a8 pmd:1e791b067
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418883] addr:0000000077da1564 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:0000000037081068 index:26b
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418890] file:libasn1.so.8.0.0 fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418893] CPU: 3 PID: 3644 Comm: gdbus Tainted: G    B D    OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418894] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/05HM5Y, BIOS 1.3.2 01/18/2017
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418896] Call Trace:
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418901]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418905]  print_bad_pte+0x222/0x2e0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418908]  ? __swap_info_get+0x61/0xa0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418910]  ? _swap_info_get+0x12/0x50
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418912]  unmap_page_range+0x91f/0xd00
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418916]  unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418918]  unmap_vmas+0x51/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418921]  exit_mmap+0xb5/0x1d0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418925]  mmput+0x57/0x140
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418927]  do_exit+0x352/0xb90
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418929]  ? try_to_wake_up+0x59/0x4a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418931]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418934]  get_signal+0x142/0x7a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418937]  do_signal+0x37/0x720
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418940]  ? __wake_up_locked_key+0x1b/0x20
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418943]  ? eventfd_write+0xd8/0x270
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418947]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0x73/0xd0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418949]  do_syscall_64+0x121/0x130
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418951]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418954] RIP: 0033:0x7f2bb4919cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418955] RSP: 002b:00007f2ba62ebca0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000007
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418957] RAX: fffffffffffffdfc RBX: 000055d30dbb2400 RCX: 00007f2bb4919cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418959] RDX: 00000000ffffffff RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000055d30dbb2400
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418960] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000055d30dbb0dd8
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418962] R10: 000055d30db9b680 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 00000000ffffffff
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418963] R13: 00000000ffffffff R14: 00007f2bb5175070 R15: 0000000000000002
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418972] swap_info_get: Bad swap file entry 2e01ffffffffffff
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418973] BUG: Bad page map in process gdbus  pte:bc00000000000000 pmd:1e791b067
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418975] addr:000000001a3b2286 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:00000000b13cc310 index:108
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418979] file:libkrb5.so.26.0.0 fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418981] CPU: 3 PID: 3644 Comm: gdbus Tainted: G    B D    OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418982] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/05HM5Y, BIOS 1.3.2 01/18/2017
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418983] Call Trace:
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418986]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418988]  print_bad_pte+0x222/0x2e0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418990]  ? __swap_info_get+0x7b/0xa0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418992]  ? _swap_info_get+0x12/0x50
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418994]  unmap_page_range+0x91f/0xd00
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418997]  unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.418999]  unmap_vmas+0x51/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419001]  exit_mmap+0xb5/0x1d0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419004]  mmput+0x57/0x140
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419006]  do_exit+0x352/0xb90
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419008]  ? try_to_wake_up+0x59/0x4a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419009]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419012]  get_signal+0x142/0x7a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419015]  do_signal+0x37/0x720
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419018]  ? __wake_up_locked_key+0x1b/0x20
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419020]  ? eventfd_write+0xd8/0x270
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419023]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0x73/0xd0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419025]  do_syscall_64+0x121/0x130
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419027]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419029] RIP: 0033:0x7f2bb4919cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419030] RSP: 002b:00007f2ba62ebca0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000007
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419032] RAX: fffffffffffffdfc RBX: 000055d30dbb2400 RCX: 00007f2bb4919cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419033] RDX: 00000000ffffffff RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000055d30dbb2400
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419034] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000055d30dbb0dd8
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419036] R10: 000055d30db9b680 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 00000000ffffffff
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419037] R13: 00000000ffffffff R14: 00007f2bb5175070 R15: 0000000000000002
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419040] swap_info_get: Bad swap offset entry 3ffff994c312c
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419041] BUG: Bad page map in process gdbus  pte:cd679da6a8 pmd:1e791b067
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419043] addr:000000007d647242 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:00000000b13cc310 index:109
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419046] file:libkrb5.so.26.0.0 fault:ext4_filemap_fault mmap:ext4_file_mmap readpage:ext4_readpage
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419048] CPU: 3 PID: 3644 Comm: gdbus Tainted: G    B D    OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419049] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360/05HM5Y, BIOS 1.3.2 01/18/2017
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419050] Call Trace:
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419052]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419054]  print_bad_pte+0x222/0x2e0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419056]  ? __swap_info_get+0x61/0xa0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419057]  ? _swap_info_get+0x12/0x50
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419059]  unmap_page_range+0x91f/0xd00
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419062]  unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xf0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419064]  unmap_vmas+0x51/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419066]  exit_mmap+0xb5/0x1d0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419069]  mmput+0x57/0x140
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419070]  do_exit+0x352/0xb90
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419072]  ? try_to_wake_up+0x59/0x4a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419074]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419076]  get_signal+0x142/0x7a0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419078]  do_signal+0x37/0x720
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419080]  ? __wake_up_locked_key+0x1b/0x20
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419082]  ? eventfd_write+0xd8/0x270
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419085]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0x73/0xd0
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419087]  do_syscall_64+0x121/0x130
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419088]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419090] RIP: 0033:0x7f2bb4919cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419091] RSP: 002b:00007f2ba62ebca0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000007
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419092] RAX: fffffffffffffdfc RBX: 000055d30dbb2400 RCX: 00007f2bb4919cb9
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419093] RDX: 00000000ffffffff RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000055d30dbb2400
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419094] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000055d30dbb0dd8
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419095] R10: 000055d30db9b680 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 00000000ffffffff
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.419096] R13: 00000000ffffffff R14: 00007f2bb5175070 R15: 0000000000000002
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 kernel: [ 9800.420289] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:0000000079376461 idx:2 val:-3
Aug  2 15:13:23 dino-XPS-13-9360 gnome-shell[3088]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Lost nameorg.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher
```

I am unable to find the cause of these freezes. Is it lack of swap, or some other hard disk issue?

**EDIT**
Output of `lshw -C memory`

```
 *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.3.2
       date: 01/18/2017
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 38
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1867 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: MT52L512M32D2PF-10
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: System Board Memory
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1867 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: MT52L512M32D2PF-10
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: System Board Memory
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 3c
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 3d
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 3e
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc32c000-dc32ffff
```

Output of `swapon -s`:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2               partition   7999484 0       -2
```

Comment: There seem to be some errors in there like `xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.` and `swap_info_get: Bad swap offset entry 3ffff994c312c` and `swap_info_get: Bad swap file entry 2e01ffffffffffff`

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Do you have swap-file? Please share the output of below commands: `lshw -C memory` and `swapon -s` .

Comment: I edited the question to include the output of the commands @N0rbert requested.

Comment: To experiment you can temporarily disable swap by `sudo swapoff -a` and then check system stability. Checking disk SMART by GNOME Disks or GSmartControl will be also useful.

Comment: I've heard that dropping back a kernel helped this problem on two other 18.04 systems (GA kernels). Don't know the cause.

Comment: @N0rbert, I looked at GSmartControl but it says "unknown model". Maybe because my harddisk is encrypted? I will try to roll back my kernel, lets see if that fixes it.